# threads in wxWidgets

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

Im using wxWidgets and I call function which takes a long time to proceed. I would like to do it in background.

How can I do that?

Thanks for help

Comment: this may help

http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_thread_helper.html

Comment: and this ... http://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Inter-Thread_and_Inter-Process_communication

Answer (score 8):

I've worked with threads in wxWidgets in pretty much all of the ways described [here](http://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Inter-Thread_and_Inter-Process_communication), and I can say that using custom events, while initially a bit more complex, saves you some headache in the long run. (The wxMessageQueue class is quite nice, but when I used it I found it to leak; I haven't checked it in about a year though.)

A basic example:

MyFrm.cpp

```
#include "MyThread.h"

BEGIN_EVENT_TABLE(MyFrm,wxFrame)
    EVT_COMMAND(wxID_ANY, wxEVT_MYTHREAD, MyFrm::OnMyThread)
END_EVENT_TABLE()
void MyFrm::PerformCalculation(int someParameter){
    //create the thread
    MyThread *thread = new Mythread(this, someParameter);
    thread->Create();
    thread->Run();
    //Don't worry about deleting the thread, there are two types of wxThreads 
    //and this kind deletes itself when it's finished.
}
void MyFrm::OnMyThread(wxCommandEvent& event)
{
    unsigned char* temp = (unsigned char*)event.GetClientData();
    //do something with temp, which holds unsigned char* data from the thread
    //GetClientData() can return any kind of data you want, but you have to cast it.
    delete[] temp; 
}
```

MyThread.h

```
#ifndef MYTHREAD_H
#define MYTHREAD_H

#include <wx/thread.h>
#include <wx/event.h>

BEGIN_DECLARE_EVENT_TYPES()
    DECLARE_EVENT_TYPE(wxEVT_MYTHREAD, -1)
END_DECLARE_EVENT_TYPES()

class MyThread : public wxThread
{
    public:
        MyThread(wxEvtHandler* pParent, int param);
    private:
        int m_param;
        void* Entry();
    protected:
        wxEvtHandler* m_pParent;
};
#endif
```

MyThread.cpp

```
#include "MyThread.h"
DEFINE_EVENT_TYPE(wxEVT_MYTHREAD)
MyThread::MyThread(wxEvtHandler* pParent, int param) : wxThread(wxTHREAD_DETACHED), m_pParent(pParent)
{
    //pass parameters into the thread
m_param = param;
}
void* MyThread::Entry()
{
    wxCommandEvent evt(wxEVT_MYTHREAD, GetId());
    //can be used to set some identifier for the data
    evt.SetInt(r); 
    //whatever data your thread calculated, to be returned to GUI
    evt.SetClientData(data); 
    wxPostEvent(m_pParent, evt);
    return 0;
}
```

I feel like this is much more clear, concise example than the one the wiki offers. Obviously I left out code concerning actually launching the app (wx convention would make that MyApp.cpp) and any other non-thread-related code.

Answer (score 2):

If you simply need to have something work in the background until it's finished -- fire and forget if you will, something like this:

```
// warning: off the top of my head ;-)
class MyThread
  : public wxThread
{
public:
  MyThread() : wxThread(wxTHREAD_DETACHED)
  {
    if(wxTHREAD_NO_ERROR == Create()) {
      Run();
    }
  }
protected:
  virtual ExitCode Entry()
  {
    // do something here that takes a long time
    // it's a good idea to periodically check TestDestroy()
    while(!TestDestroy() && MoreWorkToDo()) {
      DoSaidWork();
    }
    return static_cast<ExitCode>(NULL);
  }
};

MyThread* thd = new MyThread(); // auto runs & deletes itself when finished
```

Answer (score 1):

A few tips from implementing the above:

1. Using MingW32 and Codeblocks I've had the following `warning: EVENT redeclared without dllimport attribute: previous dllimport ignored`. The soultion to this is that if you do not need to export your events, use `DEFINE_LOCAL_EVENT_TYPE` and `DECLARE_LOCAL_EVENT_TYPE` (instead of `DEFINE_EVENT_TYPE` and `DECLARE_EVENT_TYPE`).
2. If you want to pass objects via `SetClientData()`, make sure you create the data using the `new` operator in the detachable thread. The calling application will then have to `delete` the data once it's copied.

For example:

```
BEGIN_DECLARE_EVENT_TYPES()
    DECLARE_LOCAL_EVENT_TYPE(wxEVT_CALC_THREAD, -1)
END_DECLARE_EVENT_TYPES()

void* MyThread::Entry()
{
    wxCommandEvent evt(wxEVT_CALC_THREAD, GetId());
    // do some work
    vector<map<int, int> > *vm = new vector<map<int, int> >();
    // perform operations with the object vm ...
    evt.SetClientData((void*)vm);
    wxPostEvent(m_pParent, evt);
}
```

and in the calling application:

```
DEFINE_LOCAL_EVENT_TYPE(wxEVT_CALC_THREAD)

// change this to your event table
BEGIN_EVENT_TABLE(..., ...)
    EVT_COMMAND(wxID_ANY, wxEVT_CALC_THREAD, ThreadDone)
END_EVENT_TABLE()

void ThreadDone(wxCommandEvent& event)
{

   vector<map<int, int> > *temp = (vector<map<int, int> > *)event.GetClientData();
   // store the data in *temp 
   delete temp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your program is simple and you don't want to mess around with threads, you may consider calling **wxWindow::Update()** periodically in your long function.